i am able to integrate the ckfinder with react with help of my custom build but not able to change the defult upload url for the file
Using the ckeditor5 with ckfinder3 in react able to interate it but not able to change the defult uplaod Url
ckeditor config
but as you see in belove image it still calling ckfinder api for uplaod & gate image
enter image description here
i have used belove script in the index file of react
  <script src="https://ckeditor.com/apps/ckfinder/3.7.0/ckfinder.js"></script>


